# How to display response data array in my React app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am trying to create a simple CRUD MERN Application. In this application data is displayed in my console, but I want it in my UI part.

Here is the console log:
[image]

This is `Alluser.js` file where I want to display console data which is coming from my backend:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { getUsers } from "./api";

const UserData = () => {
  const [users, setUser] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    AllUsers();
  }, []);

  const AllUsers = async () => {
    const response = await getUsers();
    console.log(response.data);
    setUser(response.data);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container">
        <table className="table table-hover table-bordered mt-3">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">No</th>
              <th scope="col">Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Email</th>
              <th scope="col">Phone</th>
              <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {users.map((index,user) => {
              <tr key={index}>
                <th scope="row">{user.id}</th>
                <td>{user.email}</td>
                <td>{user.name}</td>
                <td>{user.phone}</td>
   
              </tr>;
            })}

           
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserData;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not displaying, because of your `map` part, where you are not returning anything. Try this:

```js
  {users.map((user, index) => (
      <tr key={index}>
        <th scope="row">{user.id}</th>
        <td>{user.email}</td>
        <td>{user.name}</td>
        <td>{user.phone}</td>
      </tr>;
  ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{users.map((user,index) => {
              <tr key={index}>
                <th scope="row">{user.id}</th>
                <td>{user.email}</td>
                <td>{user.name}</td>
                <td>{user.phone}</td>
   
              </tr>;
            })}
```

Map function has 2 parameters which the first is your element

Answer (score 0):

When you are mapping over an array of values, the order of the parameters of the map function should be maintained which is

```
map((user) => { ... })
map((user, index) => { ... })
map((user, index, array) => { ... })
```

In your code, you have mentioned the index parameter before the user parameter which will give you `undefined` when you try to access the user.[anything].

if you change the order of user and index, it should work.

also, some free advice on the code : using the index as the key is not one of the best approaches as mentioned in the official docs, you can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)